# Do slime mold expand or multiply?

Tags: growth

After reading about slime mold I was wondering, do slime mold simply **expand** outwards or **multiply**?

e.g. if I put 100 grams of slime mold in 1 location, will it expand to say, 2 locations, and have the 1st location with 80 grams left, and 2nd location with 20 grams (i.e total 100 grams), or is it that they multiply; 1st location still 100 grams, and 2nd location with 20 grams?

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question expressed in grams and locations. I suggest a question about multiplication would be better expressed in number of cells in the first instance, with the size of the cells a second parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that they will do either or both, depending on conditions: this is one of the things that has caused complex systems scientists to be so interested in things like [using slime molds in modeling optimization problems](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2010/01/ride-slime-mold-express).

In good nutritional conditions, the cells will happily multiply. At the same time, they will [flow and reshape themselves to spread and migrate in search of food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physarum_polycephalum#Situational_behavior) when nutrients are not uniform.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea about the growth rate (e.g. multiplications)? I was trying to find it but couldn't. If you are familiar with any paper/sources that would be great!

Comment: I haven't personally worked with it, just heard about it from colleagues who wanted to do slime-mold computing.